# Find mean of Weibull 3 distribution in R

Tags: r, distribution, survival-analysis, weibull

Given alpha, lambda and phi (shape, scale and "guarantee"time (time before any failures), how do I find the mean of the distribution?
qweibull3 gives the median.
rweibull3 makes a nice random sample that approximates the mean, but is not the theoretical value.

Comment: Is [this](http://reliawiki.org/index.php/The_Weibull_Distribution#The_Mean_or_MTTF) what you want? Maybe this question is better asked in [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Have you searched Wikipedia? It's pretty useful for these distribution questions.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for definitions from wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution

```
weibull3_mean <- function(gtime, shape, scale) {
    gtime + scale*gamma(1.0+1.0/shape)
}
```